# PowerBI Rankx Returning only 1

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called Commissions summary that are for sales reps
This table generates a summary row for each sales rep for each month. I want to rank the sales rep only by each month, however my formula is only returning 1's.

---

**The table can be simplified down to this**

```
Sales reps     Target Attainment 
John, deer     53%
Jane, Joe      160% 
Adam, Smith    30%
```

---

**My goal is to show my table like this**

```
Sales reps     Target Attainment     Rank
John, deer     53%                    2
Jane, Joe      160%                   1
Adam, Smith    30%                    3
```

---

This is the Rankx formula I am using

```
Ranks =
RANKX (
    ALL ( 'Commission Summary' ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Commission Summary'[Target Attainment] ),
        'Commission Summary'[Date] = 10 / 01 / 2019
    ),
    ,
    DESC
)
```

As I mentioned earlier, I am only filtering my date to October.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem occurs into calculate's filter `'Commission Summary'[Date] = 10 / 01 / 2019`. The engine is dividing each number first 10/01 = 10 and 10/2019 = 0.00495 that date doesn't exist in your data returning blank for all values giving as a result a ranking with 1 in all ocurrences (because all are the same blank value).

To avoid this problem use `'Commission Summary'[Date] = DATE(2019,10,1)` as filter context. That will return a ranking properly sorted, but you'll have ranked all sales reps including sales reps who had no activity that date (they will be in the bottom of the ranking)

If you want to go a step further i recommend using the following steps:

1. create a measure first:

   `Comission Summary Filtered = CALCULATE (
       SUM ( 'Commission Summary'[Target Attainment] ),
       'Commission Summary'[Date] = DATE(2019,10,1)`
2. Then filter by that measure with the following code:

`Rank =
IF (
    [Comision Summary Filtered] > 0,
    RANKX ( ALL ( 'Commission Summary' ), [Comision Summary Filtered],, DESC, DENSE )
)`

With that you'll have a cleaner result. :)

Comment: Clarification: The filter for this answer is a **date** not a **month** if you want to filter by month use `MONTH(Commission Summary'[Date]) = 1)` as filter context (the outcome is filtered by january)